# RF PCB Design Inductor length conciderations

Tags: pcb, rf, inductor, reflection

I am making a RF amplifier for my Communications Electronics course. I am looking at creating a PCB for it and figuring out how to get the desired reflection coefficient which I will most likely use a matching networks technique for.
I have not seen anything talking about taking into account the total length of an inductor for the electrical length *L* (such as seen below). Is there any kind of factor that should be considered for this and/or the gap in a capacitor?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any inductor in your schematic. Can you be more clear what you're asking about? Also, what is your operating frequency?

Comment: I found the mistake, I was mixing up discrete and line matching design. Those "inductors" in my mind were just some impedance Z represented by the box. But the operating frequency is 1.93-1.99 GHz.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not inductors, they are lengths of transmission line.

The length has been given in units of lambda, so it's electrical length, not physical length. Make sure you know the velocity constant for your particular implementation before you scale the electrical to the physical length.

Make sure you know what impedance line your schematic is calling for.

Comment: Ah, I see where I was getting mixed up. I was treating the transmission line as some impedance Z (either inductor or capacitor) and getting mixed up by combining Line matching and discrete component design. Thank you very much.